# Turn on Bluetooth without notifying user - Android phone

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

Is there any way to turn on Bluetooth without notifying user?

I m aware about android Bluetooth working, it notifies user whenever Bluetooth on as toast "**Bluetooth turned on**" i m able to turn on Bluetooth by the help of code, But i do not want it to show notification "**Bluetooth turned on**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
if (mBluetoothAdaper != null) {
    mBluetoothAdapter.enable(); 
}
```

don't forget permissions:

```
android.permission.BLUETOOTH
android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
```

**edit:** if you just don't want the message to appear, just delete:

`Toast.maketext(context, "Bluetooth turned on", Toast.LENGHT.SHORT).show();`

somewhere in your code.

Comment: User has already mentioned that he is aware about how to enable it using code, He wants to know how to disable toast notification which is displayed when Bluetooth is activated.

Comment: when bluethooth is trun on from code and this code will not  notify user stating that "Bluethoth is trun on " ? @Strider

Comment: @Rajen Raiyarela  you are right , do you have any idea how can i achieve my aim, if you know, please help me

Comment: @Rahulkumar and my above code will indeed not inform the user that bluetooth is enabled, it just enables it!

Comment: checking your code now , Please alow some time Strider

Comment: nope. it does not work at all . showing error "NulpointerExpection"  @Strider

Comment: @Rahulkumar Try now ;) I changed it